Pell equation for composite numbers such as $n=p_1p_2$
Suppose that $n$ is not a square number and it is product of two primes as $n=p_1p_2$. Is there a relation between Pell equation for $n$, $p_1$ and $p_2$?
Pell equation is given by
\begin{equation}
x^2-ny^2=1
\end{equation}
where the integer numbers are important. I know that the solution of Pell equation can be given as $(x_1+\sqrt{n}y_1)^k$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the smallest nontrivial solution of a given Pell equation.

you might enjoy this https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/implementation.pdf

here is an example:  $59 \cdot 61 = 3599, ; ;$  and Pell  solution $60^2 - 3599 \cdot 1^2 = 1. ; ; $  However, $530^2 - 59 \cdot 69^2 = 1$   and then $1766319049^2 - 61 \cdot 226153980^2 = 1.$  Not much of the sort of relationship you want.
